# WC_Geolocation not found inside plugin

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

When I try with this code in `functions.php` file `WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip()` for getting current user country It's working fine.

But when I want to do it the same thing **from a plugin**, It throwing an error **Fatal error: Class 'WC_Geolocation' not found**

I have googled it and tried to find any possible solutions but didn't get it, please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the problem is because your plugin loads before Woocommerce plugin.

You should use it after Woocommerce is loaded, you have a hook to know that: woocommerce_init

Here you have a example to make a plugin of woocommerce:
https://www.skyverge.com/blog/creating-custom-plugin-for-your-woocommerce-shop/

I hope it helps
Regards.